# VSTS Continuous Deployment of Azure Function fails - ERROR_FILE_IN_USE

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines

Here's what I get when VSTS builds the function (made in VS2017, C#):

Info: Updating file (intr\bin\CheckNewBlob.dll).
Failed to deploy web package to App Service.
Try to deploy app service again with Rename locked files option selected.
Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
Error: C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe failed with return code: 4294967295

I set 'Take app offline' in the Deploy task but that didn't help.

Now, it says **Try to deploy app service again with Rename locked files option selected**. Where is this option? Can't find it (in VSTS).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Rename Locked Files" option only shows up once you have selected "Publish using Web Deploy", see the screenshot below:

[image: Rename Locked Files]